# Displaying one record from one to many table for each user in user list

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of users.

Every user has a contract history, all contracts stored in same table.

Every user has 1 contract that is currently active.

I'm trying to display some details from the currently active contract in the user list.

Model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    contract_start = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    contract_end = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

View:

```
def get(self, request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    date_today = timezone.now().date()
    active_contract = Contract.objects.filter(contract_start__lte=date_today, contract_end__gte=date_today)
    return render(request, 'user/list.html', {
        'users': users,
        'active_contract': active_contract,
    })
```

Template:

```
{% for user in users %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.employee.location }}</td>
    <td>{{    ??    }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In an other view where there is one user, I can add `user_id = id` to the filter and I can display the details that I want. I can't seem to get this to work in my user list though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that each user has one contract active then you can do

```py
def get(self, request):
    date_today = timezone.now().date()
    active_contracts = Contract.objects.select_related('user').filter(contract_start__lte=date_today, contract_end__gte=date_today)
    return render(request, 'user/list.html', {
        'active_contracts': active_contracts,
    })
```

Template

```
{% for contact in active_contracts %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ contact.user.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.user.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.user.employee.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.contract_start }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if I have more tables like this that need to go in the same list, the same problem would occur.

Comment: @user1880554 you can do something like



```python
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    user.active_contract = user.contract_set.filter(start__lte=date_today, end__gte=date_today).last()
```

Comment: @user1880554 @user1880554 you can do something like



```
users = User.objects.all()

for user in users:

    user.active_contract = user.contract_set.filter(start__lte=date_today, end__gte=date_today).last()
```